# How to Filter Data Name and Add The Quantity of that Filtered Data

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter

I'm attempting to create a data in which the number is added if the colors and sizes are the same. To illustrate what I mean, below is my code.

## Code

```
const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Product A",
    attributes: [
      {
        color: "Red",
        size: "Small",
        qty: 200,
      },
      {
        color: "Red",
        size: "Medium",
        qty: 100,
      },
      {
        color: "Red",
        size: "Large",
        qty: 300,
      },
      {
        color: "Yellow",
        size: "Small",
        qty: 200,
      },
      {
        color: "Yellow",
        size: "Medium",
        qty: 100,
      },
      {
        color: "Yellow",
        size: "Large",
        qty: 300,
      },
    ],
  },
];

const attributeList = data.flatMap(({ attributes }) => {
  return attributes.map((item) => {
    return item.color;
  });
});

console.log(attributeList);
```

What I'm aiming for is a result that looks like this, for example.

**For the Color:**
According tot he data stated above, **Color Red** is `600`, and **Color Yellow** the same quantity `600` when been added.

```
[600, 600]
```

**For the Size:**
According to the data stated above the **Size Small** is `400`, while the **Size Medium** is `200`, and the **Size Large** is `600`.

```
[400, 200, 600]
```

Comment: Please share your strategy here. What exact algo you are using to get results?

Comment: Hello, I just wanted to get each color like the same for example the "Red", it should be categorized already instead of hard coding it. I just wanted to get the Total Quantity of Each Color and Sizes separately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way for the color

```js
const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Product A",
    attributes: [
      {
        color: "Red",
        size: "Small",
        qty: 200,
      },
      {
        color: "Red",
        size: "Medium",
        qty: 100,
      },
      {
        color: "Red",
        size: "Large",
        qty: 300,
      },
      {
        color: "Yellow",
        size: "Small",
        qty: 200,
      },
      {
        color: "Yellow",
        size: "Medium",
        qty: 100,
      },
      {
        color: "Yellow",
        size: "Large",
        qty: 300,
      },
    ],
  },
];

const attributeList = data.flatMap(({ attributes }) => {
  let qt = {
    color: {}
  }
  let color = [];
  attributes.map((item) => {
    
    if (qt.color.hasOwnProperty(item.color)){
      qt.color[item.color] += item.qty
    }
    else {qt.color[item.color] = item.qty;}
  });
  for(let val in qt.color){
    color.push(qt.color[val])
}

return color
});

console.log(attributeList);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, it is just what I needed all along, I applied also to the size instead of color it works fine too. Thanks so much, already upvoted and made it a solution

Answer (score 0):

I hope this code helping you

Sort by Color:

```
var color = ["Red","Yellow"]
data.map(o=>color.map(v=>o.attributes.reduce((sum,prev)=>prev.color === v?sum+prev.qty: sum,0)))
```

Sort by Size:

```
var size = ["Small","Medium","Yellow"]

data.map(o=>size.map(v=>o.attributes.reduce((sum,prev)=>prev.color === v?sum+prev.qty: sum,0
)))
```

Comment: Explanation of what code should do is always more helpful than a bunch of poorly formatted code.

Comment: It does what i needed but since I wanted it to be dynamic not hard coded is there any way to remove duplicates instead of hard coding it `var color = ["Red", "Yellow"]`